# SQLite Updating tables with read only data to App users

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to the android development and having certain concerns below

(i)In my app i am using SQLite database in which user should only be able to read the data (so i am running only reading the db query in app code)
db = openOrCreateDatabase("PersonDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL(SELECT * FROM persons);

(ii)To display fresh data(eg news etc) to users i need to update my tables every day but i am not sure how to do that ?

PS: I know the code of how to make users to insert data by using an android app but here in this case only i want to insert the data(not by the users of app)
Can someone help me on this one?
Thanks! in advance﻿

Comment: If YOU must update the data for all your users, then use a web service.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a **SyncAdapter** with periodic sync that runs each day to update the database.
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Also you if you can integrate your backed with Google cloud messaging (or the newer FireBase cloud messaging) to notify the app to retrieve fresh data when available
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

In both cases, you'll retrieve data from the server and update the db within a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) so that the updates take place even if the app is not running.

**UPDATE:**

In case of SyncAdapter, the data transfer code can be implemented in the **onPerformSync()** method. As for updating the databse, SyncAdapter plays nice with [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) which makes the CRUD operations easier.

So in that method, you'll fetch the data from the network, open the database for writing and insert/update new data records. the SyncAdapter has a [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html#getContext()) method that you can use for any context operations.

You can also check this application I implemented, it has a SyncAdapter and ContentProvider.
https://github.com/MinaSamy/WeatherApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bloodstone/weather/sync/WeatherSyncAdapter.java

Comment: Thanks! i agree with SynsAdapter ,but how to update the database?

Comment: Can you please tell what does that mean "you'll fetch the data from the network"

Comment: It means that you'll retrieve the new data from your web services, you can ignore it if you don't have a web backend